# A state change do not fire componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that gets from an API call all the data to store it to a state. And it passes this state down to a component that renders this data. I wanted to add filters to that data: depending on the state of this filters the the data of the API must be filtered according and passed down to the component that renders, but the state is not updated when changing the filters state.

Code simplified

```js
class Leaderboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [],
      filtered: [],
      filterSelected: 'sport,brand',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.firebase.cards().on('value', snapshot => {
      const cardsObject = snapshot.val()
      const cardList = Object.keys(cardsObject).map(key => ({
        ...cardsObject[key],
        uid: key,
      }));
      const filtered = cardList.filter(current => {
        return current.parameter === 'sport'
      })
      this.setState({
        cards: cardList,
        filtered: filtered,
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const handleFilterChange = event => {
      this.setState({filterSelected: event.target.value})
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Typography>LEADERBOARD</Typography>
        <Box>
          <Select
            id="filter-select"
            value={this.state.filterSelected}
            onChange={handleFilterChange}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'sport'}>Sport</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'brand'}>Brand</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </Box>
        <Grid container>
          <Table list={this.state.filtered} />
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the other component that should render the filtered content

```js
export default function Table({list}) {
  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>H1</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">H2</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">H3</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {list.map(current=> (
            <TableRow key={current.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {player.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{current.parameter}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{current.location}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

The result is at first load the results are filtered according the initial state, so for instance total number of items in cards state is 41 and filtered state is 26, so filtering at first is working. But when I modify the state for filterSelected state the component nor filtered state do not updates itself. The expected result I want is filtered state to be updated every time filterSelected state updates its value.

What's wrong with my approach? There is a better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Is your firebase handler firing? Unrelated, but I don't see any reason to create `handleFilterChange` in your render method.

Comment: Use componentDidUpdate for subsequent rerenders

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentDidMount` is fired one time only. This is how it is working. It is triggered only once immediately after the initial rendering. You should use also `ComponentDidUpdate` . I encourage you to better convert this class component to be a functional component and use `useState` and `useEffect` hooks.